# Consulta usando "SUBSTR" do Firebird com linq, queryOver, Criteria

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, criteria, linq-to-sql

Galera, preciso criar uma consulta utilizando a função "SUBSTR" do firebird com linq, queryOver ou Criteria. Tenho opção de criar com HQL ou SQL, mas estas seria minhas ultimas opções.

Alguem tem uma ideia? Segue abaixo exemplo da consulta.

```
SELECT *
 FROM LANCAMENTO
 WHERE SUBSTR(LAN_CD_CONTA, 1, 13) = :paramCd_Conta
```

Comment: O que esse `SUBSTR` faz? Talvez se ele não for possível tenha alguma alternativa!

Comment: @Fernando, É uma função do firebird, que é semelhante ao substring, pega o valor de uma posição (1) até outra posição (13).

Comment: Se a consulta for algo assim: `SELECT * FROM LANCAMENTO WHERE substring(LAN_CD_CONTA from cast(@paramStart as INTEGER)+1 for cast(@paramEnd as INTEGER))=@paramCd_Conta;` onde `@paramStart` = 1 e `@paramEnd` = 13. Tem algo que não vai atender com o método `substring` do Firebird?